# Cannot change default Permission String of Expo Plugins (Camera etc.)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, info.plist

**Expo / IOS**

I'm trying to push an app to the app store and got stuck at this phase: I can not change the default permission string for using camera, photos and location. As you may well know, Apple requires that there's a detailed explanation to the reason behind requesting permission.

In `app.json`, I have changed both the `ios.infoPlist.NSCameraUsageDescription` as well as the specific plugin permission text string at `plugins.expo-camera.cameraPermission`.

Neither of them works. The text is the old one.

How can I change this successfully?

`app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to take a photo of users 
        for their profiles, and optionally to take a photo of a book that users choose to 
        manually add to their virtual book shelves."
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-camera",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "This app uses the camera to take a photo of users 
          for their profiles, and optionally to take a photo of a book that users choose 
          to manually add to their virtual book shelves."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: I've read and tried to fix through this: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

It was a super easy solution. Run the prebuild command with `clean` flag before running build:

`npx expo prebuild --platform ios --clean`